# Question involving Martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a probability space $(\Omega, M, P)$
and non-negative integrable functions on $\Omega \times [0,1]$, $F_1(\omega, t)$
and $F_2(\omega, t)$. For each $t \in [0,1]$ we have that $F_1(\omega, t)$ and $F_2(\omega, t)$ are independent. Also $ \int_{\Omega} F_n(\omega, t) dP(\omega) = 1  $ for each $t$.

Let $X_1(\omega) = \int_a^b F_1(t,\omega) \ dt$, $0 \leq a< b \leq 1$.

Given any $A \in \sigma(X_1)$ (this is the smallest sigma 
algebra to make $X_1$ measurable).
I am trying to show that

$$
\int_A \int_a^b F_1(\omega, t)F_2(\omega, t) dt \ dP(\omega) = \int_A X_1(\omega) \ dP(\omega)
$$

I would appreciate any hint, solutions, comments! 
Thanks!

Comment: Replaced $dP$ by $dP(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Use Tonelli/Fubini's theorem to show that the double integrals can be interchanged
$$
\int_a^b \int_A F_1(\omega,t)F_2(\omega,t)\,\mathrm dP(\omega)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Now write the innermost integral as an expectation and use that the random variables $$\omega\mapsto F_1(\omega,t)1_A(\omega)\quad\text{and}\quad\omega\mapsto F_2(\omega,t)$$ are independent for all $t$ along with the fact that $E[F_2(\cdot,t)]=1$ for all $t$.

Comment: The part I am having the most difficulty understanding is how to show these two random variables $F_1 (\omega,t) 1_A(\omega)$ and $F_2(\omega,t)$ are independent. Do we not need a condition like $\sigma(X_1)$ is independent of $\sigma(F_1(\omega,t), F_2(\omega, t) ) $ for each $t$? Could you possibly explain me this part a little more? Thank you!

Comment: You're right. I think I was too fast in stating that $F_1(\cdot,t)\cdot 1_A$ and $F_2(\cdot,t)$ are independent, because $1_A$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_1)$ which depends on $F_1(\cdot,t)$ for $a\leq t\leq b$. Are you sure the independence condition is that for every $t$: $F_1(\cdot,t)$ and $F_2(\cdot,t)$ is independent and not $F_1(\cdot,t)$ is independent of $F_2(\cdot,s)$ for all $s$?

Comment: Thank you so much! I am also starting to think maybe it is a mistake...

Comment: So I think it is a mistake so I am going to try it with the stronger assumption. Thank you!

Comment: I also have a question related to this.. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355026/independence-of-a-function-and-integral-of-a-function